# 'toggleClass' not working on every other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

For some strange reason this simple click function I've added, which should be adding the 'big' class to the clicked divs, is only working for every other div.

[See an example here](http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/extramiletest/index.html) (click the square boxes with images)

```
$('.box').click(function(){

$(this).toggleClass('big').siblings().removeClass('big');

});
```

Here is a fiddle but I chose not to post this as it works fine as it should do. The error is caused by some other element but I don't know what 
http://jsfiddle.net/Ly1bxswq/1/

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Maybe it is because every other element has a different class.

Comment: no, all elements have the class '.big' which the javascript is calling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You binding your `click` handler within a loop, but need to do it only once when all elements added to page.

```
$.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, entry) {
  // ...
  $container.append(item);
  // ...
})

$('.box').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('big').siblings().removeClass('big');
}
```

As pointed out by **@Yan Brunet**'s comment, it would be much better to delegate the event from every `.box` to their parent. That way you can bind your handler at any point (even before `.box` elements are added to page)

```
$container.on("click", ".box", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('big').siblings().removeClass('big');
});
```

Comment: It would be better to delegate the event in this fashion :     `$('#content').on("click", ".box", function(){});`

Comment: @YanBrunet, yep, you are right it would be much better. Just figured out what the problem before doing suggestions, I'll add it in a second.

Comment: That was a funny one. bboy beatle:  Using a delegate would have prevented this behavior, since it would apply regardless of when the element is created. Performance wise it's also better (only 1 handler is created instead of 1 per `.box` item)